# Передача массива(в методе Random) в другое Activity

Tags: android

Есть два строковых одномерных массива и есть две кнопки для каждого из них. Надо их передать в другое активити (в зависимости какая кнопка нажата), а там вывести в `TextView` рандомный элемент переданного массива. Передаю через `Bundle`.

Подскажите как можно это сделать?

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    int random = (int) (Math.random() * tSize);
    String randomArray = arr[random];
    Bundle bundleTruth =new Bundle();
    bundleTruth.putStringArray("Truth", new String[]{randomArray});
    Intent intentTruth=new Intent(SelectionActivity.this, GameActivity.class);
    intentTruth.putExtras(bundleTruth);
    startActivity(intentTruth, bundleTruth);
...
```

Получаю я:

```
Bundle bundleTruth=this.getIntent().getExtras();
String[] arrayTruth =bundleTruth.getStringArray("Truth");
```

P.S. опыта почти нет, чтобы самому разобраться.

Comment: Скорее всего у вас NullPointerException попробуйте поискать причину и обработать. должно заработать.

Comment: да все так,спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Надо создать проект и добавить в него две пустые активити: `MainActivity` и `GameActivity`. Это делается через GUI, надеюсь, справитесь. В полученные активити скопировать и вставить код ниже, добавив нужные импорты (студия сама подскажет).

Примечание 1: О создании активити и навигации между ними можно почитать в [официальной документации](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html).

Примечание 2: Использовать `AppCompatActivity` не обязательно, можно пользоваться и обычными `Activity`.

Примечание 3: умоляю, никогда не называйте переменные именами типа "t", "ran" или "inT". Не ленитесь и давайте им осмысленные имена, особенно приводя код в вопросе.

Код `MainActivity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String[] firstArray;
    private String[] secondArray;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        firstArray = generateArray(10);
        secondArray = generateArray(10);

        ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.firstListTextView)).setText(printArray(firstArray));
        ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.secondListTextView)).setText(printArray(secondArray));
    }

    private String[] generateArray(int count) {
        Random random = new Random();
        String[] result = new String[count];
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            result[i] = String.valueOf(random.nextInt(1000));
        }
        return result;
    }

    private String printArray(String[] array) {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        for (String item : array) {
            result.append(item).append('\n');
        }
        return result.toString();
    }

    public void goFirst(View view) {
        GameActivity.open(this, firstArray);
    }

    public void goSecond(View view) {
        GameActivity.open(this, secondArray);
    }
}
```

Разметка `R.layout.activity_main`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="org.example.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/firstListTextView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:text="TextView"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="9dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/secondListTextView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:text="TextView"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/firstGoButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Go"
        android:onClick="goFirst"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/firstListTextView" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/secondGoButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Go"
        android:onClick="goSecond"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/secondListTextView" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Код `GameActivity`:

```
public class GameActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String EXTRA_ARRAY = "GameActivity.Array";

    public static void open(Activity caller, String[] array) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(caller, GameActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_ARRAY, array);
        caller.startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);

        String[] array = getIntent().getStringArrayExtra(EXTRA_ARRAY);
        if (array != null) {
            String result = array[new Random().nextInt(array.length)];
            ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.resultTextView)).setText(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Разметка `R.layout.activity_game`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="org.example.myapplication.GameActivity">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/resultTextView"
        tools:text="Result"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: вопрос немного в другом есть два строчных массива имеющие уже свои параметры,и две кнопки по нажатию кнопки передается массив в другое активити(какой зависти от нажатой кнопки) а там уже выводится значение одного элемента(рандомного) элемента, передать по одному я могу но потом Активити не понимает какой передан массив и крашится

Comment: Как насчёт того, чтобы добавить в интент ещё один параметр, который показывает, какой именно из двух массивов передаётся, если так важно знать, какой это именно массив?

Comment: да я это понимаю я пытаюсь использовать containsKey, но не понимаю как получить в другом активити выбранный массив

Comment: или подскажите другой метод подобный containsKey

Comment: Если что, у интента есть метод [`hasExtra`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#hasExtra(java.lang.String)), который работает по сути так же, как и `containsKey` для `HashMap`.

Comment: А если надо передать коллекцию объектную то что лучше использовать?